# Find the value for all the ids

Tags: r

I have the following dataset

```
dts1 <- data.frame (id = c(1,2,3,2,1), transactionID =c ("A","","", "B","A"))
```

I wish to copy the value of transactionID for all of them

so I want to convert this:

```
 id transactionID
1  1             A
2  2              
3  3              
4  2             B
5  1             A
```

to

```
 id transactionID
    1  1             A
    2  2             B 
    3  3              
    4  2             B
    5  1             A
```

Which is my ideal output
Because the transactionID for id 2 is missed in the second row and I replaced it.

I tried this

```
library(dplyr)
dts1 %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(transactionID = paste(transactionID, collapse=""))
```

Which gives me the following:

```
id transactionID
  (dbl)         (chr)
1     1            AA
2     2             B
3     3              
4     2             B
5     1            AA
```

Comment: It's not really a great approach, but you can just wrap `transactionID` in `unique` to make it work: `dts1 %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(transactionID = paste(unique(transactionID), collapse=""))`

Comment: Thanks alistair, I really need a facepalm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dts1)[, transactionID := if(all(!nzchar(as.character(transactionID)))) transactionID
         else transactionID[nzchar(as.character(transactionID))][1], by = id]
dts1
#   id transactionID
#1:  1             A
#2:  2             B
#3:  3              
#4:  2             B
#5:  1             A
```

Answer (score 1):

With base R / match:

```
lookup <- unique(dts1[dts1$transactionID != '',])
dts1$transactionID <- lookup[match(dts1$id, lookup[,1]),2]
dts1$transactionID[is.na(dts1$transactionID)] <- ''

dts1

  id transactionID
1  1             A
2  2             B
3  3              
4  2             B
5  1             A
```